# In python with matplotlib, can rectangle patches have an image texture / fill?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'd like to display several figures in a 3D space.

So far, I got one rectangle in 3D space using [THIS](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/pathpatch3d.html):

[image: Matplotlib figure]

Relevant code snippet:

```
# Draw a rectangle on the x=0 'wall'
p = Rectangle((6.5,2.5),5,5,90)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=5, zdir="x")
```

Where 'rectangle' refers to matplotlib.patches.rectangle

Now, the rectangle is blue. Can I change it to become an image?